# wpf and asp.net databinding elementname

Tags: asp.net, wpf, data-binding

I know how the elementname binding works in WPF and was wondering if I could do the same in asp.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean in Silverlight, then yes, as of Silverlight 3 (.NET 4/VS2010).  If you actually mean ASP.Net, then no, at least not using the same syntax.

Comment: In asp.net not silverlight. It does not matter what the syntax is. I have a solution with javascript and looking for an alternative and easy solution.

Comment: You may want to reword your question, providing some detail of what you want to do.  It is very vague.